# How to load elastic data in python using scroll?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an index in elastic search which is having huge data. I am trying to load some of its data (more than 10000 records)in python for further processing. As per documentation and web search **scroll** is used but it is able to fetch only few records. After sometime this exception occurs,

```
 errorNotFoundError(404, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No search context found for id [101781]')
```

My code is as following:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

##########elastic configuration
host='localhost'
port=9200
user=''
pasw=''
el_index_name = 'test'


es = Elasticsearch([{'host':host , 'port': port}], http_auth=(user,pasw))
res = es.search(index=el_index_name, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}},scroll='10m')

rows=[]
while True:
    try:
        rows.append(es.scroll(scroll_id=res['_scroll_id'])['hits']['hits'])
    except Exception as esl:
        print ('error{}'.format(esl))
        break

##deleting scroll
es.clear_scroll(scroll_id=res['_scroll_id'])
```

I have changed the value of **scroll='10m'** but still, this exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your scroll request line to this:

```
rows.append(es.scroll(scroll_id=res['_scroll_id'], body={"scroll": "10m","scroll_id": res['_scroll_id']})['hits']['hits'])
```

As an advice, It is better to increase number of retrieved posts. retrieving just 1 post in each request have negative influence on your performance and it has overhead for your cluster, as well. as an example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },"size":100
}
```

I have added the below part to answer to the question in comments. It is not stopping because you have put `While True` in your code. You need to change it to this:

```
res = es.search(index=el_index_name, body={"query": {"match_all": {}}}, scroll='10m')
scroll_id = res['_scroll_id']
query = {
    "scroll": "10m",
    "scroll_id": scroll_id
}

rows = []
while len(res['hits']['hits']):
    for item in res['hits']['hits']:
        rows.append(item)

    res = es.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, body=query)
```

Please let me know if there was any problem with this.

Comment: The while loop does not stop, there are 12619 records in total, res['hits']['total']['value']=12619. But its not stopping, it is reading never ending number of records.

Comment: Hi, I added a complete code to solve your problem. Please check and let me know it it worked or not. Thanks!

Comment: I used scanners to load all data.